# I have changed my server, Do I need to re generate the ssl key

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, keys

I am using AWS for hosting. I have got one productions instance and pre-production instance in  it. I have installed ssl to the production site. But unfortunately its crashed. So we cloned the pre-production and make it to production, We have installed the old ssl keys in the new production server, unfortunately ssl not working on it.

Comment: Can you give more details as to what is not working?

Comment: HTTPS url is not working... The domain was pointed to server instance in AWS, which is crashed, so we pointed it to new instance and make the site up. But the Secure url is not working with. we have installed all the certificates in the new server as we did in the previous server.

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'not working'?  What error messages do you get? Is there anything in the webserver's error logs?

Comment: its showing The site's security certificate is not trusted!

Comment: Have you also copied (and configured) any chaining certificates from the old server?

Comment: These are the errors showing in sslchecker. 1) The certificate is self-signed. Users will receive a warning when accessing this site unless the certificate is manually added as a trusted certificate to their web browser. You can fix this error by buying a trusted SSL certificate 2 ) None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors.

Comment: I have copied it from there

Comment: You say you're using the production key and certificate from the old server, which latter is presumably a professionally-signed certificate.  The `sslchecker` output you're giving us suggests that the apache server isn't using that keypair.  At this point, it would be very helpful to see the relevant bits of the apache config, and any error logs **from the server** (as Flup already requested).

Answer (score 0):

If you did not make a backup copy of the private keys attached to your SSL certificate, then your only option is to generate a new request and ask your CA to sign it again. Some commercial provider will do it for free the first time (for the same FQDN), others will ask for a small fees, some will require a completely new payment.

Also, next time, generate the key outside your production machine and keep a backup of your private key in a safe place (i.e. not in a networked location: that key **is** your reputation).

Comment: Thanks @Stephane . We have all the key with us ,Nothing has lost. Please let me know how can I use the old keys ?

Comment: if you still have the private keys, then you can reinstall them the same way you installed them in the first place (check your software documentation)

Comment: I did it after that its showing "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" error in browsers

Comment: These are the errors showing in sslchecker. 1) The certificate is self-signed. Users will receive a warning when accessing this site unless the certificate is manually added as a trusted certificate to their web browser. You can fix this error by buying a trusted SSL certificate
  
2 ) None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors.